# PHP Parse Error JSON Exception With Redundant Value - Failed To Fetch Datacom

Tags: java, php, json, android-volley

I was in the middle of getting my data from my server (XAMPP), and I'm having a problem regarding with the return format (I believed). I was getting my data and put it in the `cardView` - `recyclerView` .

This is my php code: `orgList.php`

```
<?php

//if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == ''){


     require('dbConnect.php');

     $SQLi_ORG_FEEDS = "SELECT organizationName,organizationDescription,organizationCategory,
                        organizationCurrentMembers,organizationMaxMembersNo,organizationType FROM org_information";

     $query = mysqli_query($dbConnect,$SQLi_ORG_FEEDS) or die("Error".mysqli_error($dbConnect));

     $checkRow = mysqli_num_rows($query);

     $response = array();
     $response["success"] = "success";
     if($checkRow > 0){
         while ($getRecord = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $response[] = $getRecord;

         }

          echo json_encode($response);
     }
     else {
         $response['failed'] = 'failed';
          echo json_encode($response);
     }

//}
```

My java: `orgFragment.java`

```
 public void parseJSONData(){
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(ServerScripts.PHP_SCRIPT_PATH + ServerScripts.PHP_GET_FEEDS, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            if (response.length() > 0){
                try {
                    organizationDataList.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++ ){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        OrganizationData organizationData = new OrganizationData();

                        //SQL TABLE NAME
                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("organizationName")){
                            organizationData.orgName = jsonObject.getString("organizationName");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("organizationType")){
                            organizationData.orgType = jsonObject.getString("organizationType");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("organizationDescription")){
                            organizationData.orgDesc = jsonObject.getString("organizationDescription");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("organizationCategory")){
                            organizationData.orgCategory = jsonObject.getString("organizationCategory");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("organizationCurrentMembers")){
                            organizationData.orgCurrentMembers = jsonObject.getInt("organizationCurrentMembers");
                        }

                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("organizationMaxMembersNo")){
                            organizationData.orgMaxMembers = jsonObject.getInt("organizationMaxMembersNo");
                        }

                        //ADD
                        organizationDataList.add(organizationData);
                    }
                        //NOTIFY
                        orgListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            String getErrorMsg = error.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Failed to Fetch Data" + getErrorMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonArray);

}
```

[image: Postman]

I check my format in postman if returned in json. And I get this response. Can someone help me with this one, the PHP coding. Where do I get wrong in JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
      echo json_encode($response);
 }
 else {
      echo $response["failed"] = "failed";
      ^^^^^^^^
```

Your client is expecting json. If the `else` clause is executed, you script outputs `failed`, which is invalid/illegal json, which will cause a parse error. You probably wanted something more like

```
 $response['failed'] = 'failed';
 echo json_encode($response);
```

This is also wrong:

```
     while ($getRecord = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                ^-- one row of result data as an array
        $response["organizationName"] = $getRecord;
                                             ^--stuff entire row array into response
```

You're also fetching MULTIPLE records from the db (otherwise, why else fetch in a loop), and continually assign the entire result row array into multiple fields of your response, then overrwrite those previous results with the next row. That means you'll only ever get the LAST record fetched from your query.

You want:

```
     while ($getRecord = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $response["organizationName"][] = $getRecord['organizationName'];
                                     ^-append to array
       etc..
     }
```

instead, or maybe just

```
     while ($getRecord = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $response[] = $getRecord;
     }
```

Comment: I find this helpful - while ($getRecord = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $response[] = $getRecord;
     }.

Comment: I still got parse error but the redundant value is now gone. How do I correct this one. I will update my post with your answer

Comment: look at the raw response received by the client. if there's ANYTHING before/after the json data you're expecting, it'll be treated as corrupt json.e.g. a php warning/error at the end will cause this. `{longjsontext}PHP Warning: blah blah blah` is no longer valid json.

Comment: How do I look for the raw response? From Debugging mode in android studio. And learning postman to track this one. I know it's not an excuse but I'm new with this one.

Comment: no idea. never done android devel before. but somewhere in there you should be able to access the raw body/headers of the http resonse.

Comment: Can you send me a picture of that one. I have no idea what it looks like. I will update my picture of this problem.